# MariaDB: Insert records (list of tuples) into table if not exists

Tags: mariadb, query, insert, subquery, mariadb-10.1

Currently I have several sql queries that look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (col1, col2)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '1','2') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `test`
    WHERE col1='1' AND col2='2'
) LIMIT 1;


INSERT INTO `test` (col1, col2)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '3','4') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `test`
    WHERE col1='3' AND col2='4'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Generally speaking, as rule of thumb the less queries the better which is why I want to rewrite the sql queries into one query. This should make it even faster when having millions of datasets as the `WHERE` clause would only iterate through the table once, hence this should be possible:

```
WHERE col1 in ('1','3') AND col2 in ('2','4')
```

But when I try multiple select statements in a single query like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT '1','2') AS tmp1,
(SELECT '3','4') AS tmp2
```

SQL throws this error:

**`#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`**

The problem is with `SELECT * FROM (SELECT '1','2') AS tmp`.

How can I use several tuples `(1, 2) (3, 4)` in the subquery for it meet the `WHERE` condition?

Is there a shorter and faster way to achieve this?

Any feedback is highly appreciated!

Please ignore the data types; the numbers should be formatted as `int` not as `varchar`.

---

**UPDATE**

When executing the following:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (col1, col2)
SELECT * FROM
((SELECT * FROM (SELECT '7','8') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `test`
    WHERE col1='7' AND col2='8'
) LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT '9','9') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `test`
    WHERE col1='9' AND col2='9'
) LIMIT 1)) t1;
```

SQL throws: **`Duplicate column name '9'`**

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?

Comment: MariaDB v10.1.48 @bbaird

Comment: Any reason not to use `insert ignore`?

Comment: No @mustaccio I use `INSERT IGNORE` to avoid duplicate entries. If there's another fast way to insert unique values into a MariaDB table, feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to build as many rows as you need:

```
INSERT INTO test
SELECT
  i.col1
 ,i.col2
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      1 AS col1
     ,2 AS col2
    
      UNION ALL
      
    SELECT 
      3
     ,4
  )  i
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        test
      WHERE
        col1 = i.col1
          AND col2 = i.col2
    )
```

See fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=d8622d944870950bf4a5d3af732990af).

After 10.3.3 MariaDB (sort of) supports [table-valued constructors](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/table-value-constructors/), you won't have the ability to name the columns like you would otherwise:

```
INSERT INTO test
SELECT
  i.`1`
 ,i.`2`
FROM
  (
    VALUES
      (1,2)
     ,(3,4)
  )  i
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        test
      WHERE
        col1 = i.`1`
          AND col2 = i.`2`
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the update on MariaDB v10.3.3 @bbaird .. Quick question about `SELECT 1`: why not use `*` instead of `1`? Plus, I like your `UNION ALL` approach. I'm still running some tests on larger datasets before marking an answer. Could you tell me how this affects the performance on a bigger scale?

Comment: @user13581602 Just preference, 1/* doesn't matter in terms of how the query will execute.  If the correlated subquery utilizes the primary key or a suitable index the size of the table is irrelevant and the only impact is the number of lookups you're performing.

Comment: Actually @bbaird your method also handles duplicate columns, which is a huge plus!

Answer (score 0):

Your `SELECT` with two select can be `JOIN`ed or `UNION`ìted

As you want to insert two rows, you need `UNION` like this

```
INSERT INTO `test` (col1, col2)
SELECT * FROM
((SELECT * FROM (SELECT '1','2') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `test`
    WHERE col1='1' AND col2='2'
) LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT '3','4') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `test`
    WHERE col1='3' AND col2='4'
) LIMIT 1)) t1;
```

I don't see why it should give you an error

```
INSERT INTO `test` (col1, col2)
SELECT * FROM
((SELECT * FROM (SELECT '1','2') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `test`
    WHERE col1='1' AND col2='2'
) LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT '3','4') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `test`
    WHERE col1='3' AND col2='4'
) LIMIT 1) 
UNION
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT '9','9') AS tmp  WHERE col1='9' AND col2='9')
) t1;
```

Comment: Thanks @nbk with `UNION` it executes the query two times faster than each of the queries individually. However, `WHERE NOT EXIST` loops through the table twice .. Is it possible to just `UNION` the `tmp` subqueries and then `WHERE col1 in ('1','3') AND col2 in ('2','4')`? I say this because the table will be very large in the future and I would have to use several hundreds of `UNION` in one query which may eventually affect the performance.

Comment: no as the values as different you can't use one exist , as they exclude each other a combination goes only if the rules apply to all. with an INDEX (col1,col2) this is **very fast**

Comment: I understand @nbk right now this is the fastest method. The table does not have an `INDEX` though, maybe I should consider adding one for better performance

Comment: yes INDEXees can help make a query faster, in your case as you are looking for one combination it would make it very fast

Comment: When I do something like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT '9','9') AS tmp` and then `WHERE col1='9' AND col2='9'`, SQL throws **`Duplicate column name '9'`** @nbk

Comment: i don't know hwat exactly you did, so i can't follow you, but see my update and notoce also the brackets around the new line